# Duplicate BuildConfig.class in android modules

Tags: android, gradle, module, buildconfig

I have two android modules that one of them has a dependency to other one, and both have same package name.

this error occurs building the project:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
```

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: ir/magnet/sdk/BuildConfig.class

To avoid the duplicate Is there a way to remove the first module's `BuildConfig.class` after build?

Comment: did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Yes! I made a jar file out of one of the modules and deleted the 'build.config' class using "WinRAR" app, then added the modifid jar file to the project instead of module itself.

Comment: lol, that's a workaround not a solution.